# Clearing iOS Keychain (physical device) before test

Tags: appium, ipa, fastlane, codesign

I am looking for a way to clear the iOS keychain for a specific app on my iOS device. While using automated tests with Appium, I'd like to be able to start from a fresh state for each test.

I tried looking into libimobiledevice, but there's no option to clear the Keychain.

When I remove the app from the device, the data is still kept in the Keychain for the specific app.

What I also tried was a different approach: resign the `.ipa`:

Either using `fastlane resign`, or extracting the entitlements from the `.ipa` and modifying the `application-identifier`, then resign with my own provisioning profile, but this also keeps using the keychain data from the original `ipa`.

What combination of application identifier/bundleId is iOS using to interact with the Keychain? If I could somehow modify and resign the `ipa`, it could ignore the Keychain values from the original `ipa`.